# PHP: Read an html file and get access to JS variable

Tags: php

Lets say I have a public html page on the internet with the following content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var variableA = {
                name: "A"
            };
            variableA.id = 1;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get the value of the variable `variableA` with php?

Something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents($myUrl);
$variableA = magicMethodIamLookingFor("variableA");
print_r($variableA);
```

With this result:

```
Array(
    "name" => "A",
    "id" => 1
)
```

I could do it just with regex and `json_decode` (similar like [How to get Javascript variable from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883428/how-to-get-javascript-variable-from-an-html-page)) but the problem is, that its not just a single json, but there are also variable changes like `variableA.id = 1;`

Comment: You can use regex to finding it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Javascript variable from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883428/how-to-get-javascript-variable-from-an-html-page)

Comment: You can for example send the variable value in a form or simply create an HTTP request and send it as URL parameter. In both cases, the target URL will be your PHP script.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy: I have no access on the public url. @Mohammad: That would be possible, but since the variable is change (`variableA.id = 1;`) it will be really tricky to do that that way

Comment: I'm not getting it. What's on the "public url"? Do you mean that you can't modify the HTML page by that?

Comment: Its not my domain. I can't modify anything on it. I am writing a crawler to crawl a couple of webpages for a specialized search engine. And on it, there is some data stored in JS variables

Answer (score 0):

**Note: With plain PHP scripting, it is not possible to access JS vars.**

Interesting requirement. Below goes a solution. Lets consider the case if the variable name is passed in the URL. Let the page name be 'index.php'. The browsing URL looks like this localhost/index.php?varName=variableA, where varName is the query param which takes variable name as value. We can pass comma separated values also by tweaking the code a bit. But that is not considered now.

Outlining the steps below

1. Get contents of url.php and place it in a hidden div of index.php
2. Beneath the captured content, call an Ajax function with var name & var value as param.
3. Inside the ajax page, save the name / value to some DB or file.
4. After the ajax call there is some more DOM where we will print the name / value & remove the record from DB or File after displaying the same.
   NB: The main code is in JS - See getVarWithValue(variable) function.

   ```
   <html>
   <body>

       <?php 
           $varName = (isset($_GET['varName']) && trim($_GET['varName']) != "") ? $_GET['varName'] : 'variableA';
       ?>

       <div style="display:none">
           <?php
               $html = file_get_contents('./url.php');
               echo $html;

           ?>
           <script>
               //THIS IS THE CORE FUNCTION WHICH GETS THE VAR NAME & VALUE
               function getVarWithValue(variable) {
                   var param = '';
                   for (var name in this) {
                       keyValue = [];
                       if (variable == name ) return param += name+'='+JSON.stringify(eval(name));
                   }
                   return false;
               }

               var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
               http.open("POST", "setVariableValue.php", false); // 3rd argument makes sure that the call is NOT async.  
               http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                       document.getElementById("varValue").innerHTML = http.responseText.toString();
                   }
               };
               http.send(getVarWithValue( '<?php echo $varName ?>' ));
           </script>
       </div>
       <?php
           //$varValue = getValuefromDB(); Get the saved value from DB or file
           echo "The variable value of $varName is: ".$varValue;
           // Write code to remove the row from DB or file
       ?>
   </body>
   ```

**url.php** (Page from which we need to capture the variable name & value)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var variableA = {  name: "A" };
            variableA.id = 1;
            var variableB = ["Stack", "Overflow"]
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some Text
    </body>
</html>
```

**setVariableValue.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Write code for saving var name & value to DB or file
*/
```