# get javascript array/variable with php from html website

Tags: javascript, php, json, variables

I have this html text and need to extract mydata from html to php

```
<script>
var mydata=[{"id":105,"i":"4.jpg"},{id":13,"i":"5.jpg"}];
//some other js code
</script>
```

I tried this in php:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$js = preg_grep("/var mydata={.*}/", $html);
$js = str_replace("var mydata=", "", $js );
$sv = json_decode($js);
print_r($sv);
```

Nothing is extracted. What am I doing wrong please?

P.S. I found similar topic here [How to get Javascript variable from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883428/how-to-get-javascript-variable-from-an-html-page)

Comment: You should probably post that data to your PHP backend instead of loading the whole file and scraping it.

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong please?”_ - for startes, you apparently must be “developing”, without having proper PHP error reporting enabled. So go and do that first of all!

Comment: And then, you need to go and read up on some regex basics. `[.*]` is the list of characters `.` and `*`. (https://regex101.com/ can offer a lot of help, if you’re still fuzzy on the details.)

Comment: @Cbroe, there is just this warning: Warning: preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: and now I updated my regex to /var mydata=\\[.*\\]/ and it works on regex101.com but always the same error on php script

Comment: `preg_grep( string $pattern, array $input...` and you're dishing it a string, that's why you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match` is solution:

```
$matches = array();
$js= preg_match("/var mydata=\[.*\]/", $html, $matches);
$match = str_replace("var mydata=", "", $matches[0]);
$sv = json_decode($match);
print_r($sv);
```